# How can I search for a keyword and print everything around it but still between the { } brackets - python

Tags: python, split, format, edit, cut

I have the string

```
{"quests ":
    [{
         "title ":"Phite Club",
         "status": "COMPLETED",
         "difficulty": 3,
         "members": True,
         "questPoints": 1,
         "userEligible": True
    },{
         "title": "All Fired Up",
         "status": "COMPLETED",
         "difficulty": 1,
         "members": True,
         "questPoints": 1,
         "userEligible": True
    }]
}
```

I want to search for `All Fired Up` and have the output be:

```
{"title": "All Fired Up", 
 "status": "COMPLETED",
 "difficulty": 1,
 "members": True,
 "questPoints": 1,
 "userEligible": True}
```

I don't necessarily need the quotes or { } in the output but either way I need the data.

My formatting is poor but any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your formatting was not great. Missing the end of the array and the end of the object and the end of the string. ]}".

Comment: Is this the _real_ string or did you fail to paste some characters?

Comment: No, that is incorrect. The JSON representation is indeed `true`.

Comment: If this is the correct string, you have some pretty advanced/ tedious string manip to do. If we saw the whole problem, and an attempt at the problem, it would be more helpful.

Comment: this is not the real string, I just gave an example to shorten it

Comment: Your example string is an _invalid fragment_ of a _possibly valid_ JSON string. If your whole string is a _valid_ JSON string, then the solution to your problem is different. So, is your _whole_ string a valid_ JSON string?

Answer (score 1):

## Answer for revised question

Let's define your dictionary:

```
>>> d = {"quests ":
...     [{
...          "title ":"Phite Club",
...          "status": "COMPLETED",
...          "difficulty": 3,
...          "members": True,
...          "questPoints": 1,
...          "userEligible": True
...     },{
...          "title": "All Fired Up",
...          "status": "COMPLETED",
...          "difficulty": 1,
...          "members": True,
...          "questPoints": 1,
...          "userEligible": True
...     }]
... }
```

To retrieve the sections of interest to you:

```
>>> [y for dd in d.values() for y in dd if y.get('title') == 'All Fired Up']
[{'questPoints': 1, 'title': 'All Fired Up', 'status': 'COMPLETED', 'userEligible': True, 'members': True, 'difficulty': 1}]
```

Or, if you know ahead of time that what you are looking for is under `quests`:

```
>>> [y for y in d['quests '] if y.get('title') == 'All Fired Up']
[{'questPoints': 1, 'title': 'All Fired Up', 'status': 'COMPLETED', 'userEligible': True, 'members': True, 'difficulty': 1}]
```

## Answer for original version of the question

Let's define your string:

```
>>> s = '"{"quests":[{"title":"Phite Club","status":"COMPLETED","difficulty":3,"members":true,"questPoints":1,"userEligible":true},{"title":"All Fired Up","status":"COMPLETED","difficulty":1,"members":true,"questPoints":1,"userEligible":true},"'
```

Let's extract the parts that you want:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\{[^}]*All Fired Up[^}]*\}', s)
['{"title":"All Fired Up","status":"COMPLETED","difficulty":1,"members":true,"questPoints":1,"userEligible":true}']
```

The regex `\{[^}]*All Fired Up[^}]*\}` matches `All Fired Up` and all characters around it up to and including the nearest `{` on the front and `}` on the back.

[Notice that, in the current version of the question, the dictionary has key `quests` with a space after `quests`.  The code above

#### The JSON Question

As I wrote this answer, the string in the question was *not* valid JSON.  If, in later updates, that is replaced with a valid JSON string, then [Daniel Roseman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331124/3030305) becomes appropriate.

Comment: This is a JSON string. Regex is not the appropriate tool.

Comment: @DanielRoseman We do not know if it is a valid JSON string. If it is not, then regex is the only option.

Comment: We don't know if it is JSON string or a fraction of a string. Regex is the only solution as the question was written.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = ".... your string ..."
data = [ s.split("}")[0] for s in string.split("{") if "All Fired Up" in s ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a JSON string. You should parse it to python and then search for your match.

```
data = json.loads(mystring)
target = next(item for item in data if item["title"] == "All Fired Up")
```

Comment: Did you try this?  It fails for me.  (Or did you modify the OP's string to be valid json?)

Comment: what should I be printing to get my desired output? heres how my response of the json is formatted "myString = response.content.decode('utf-8')"